# Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'. Cannot constrain type: @Null NULL for value: ... by constraint: INT

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-r8

When I try to generate .apk file minifyR8 gives error like this

```
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'. Cannot constrain type: @Null NULL for value: v59(0) by constraint: INT
```

It happens after I updated Android Studio, changed jcenter() to mavenCentral()

[image]

and buildToolsVersion from "29.0.3" to "30.0.3".

How to solve this problem? I do not quite understand the meaning, since there were no such problems before. Anyway what is v59(0) value?

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @GreenROBO Unfortunately not. Are you facing the same problem?

Comment: I solve this problem by downgrading my NDK version from 22.1.7171670 to 20.1.5948944 as the Latest NDK version was causing the issue.

Comment: @GreenROBO Lucky. This solution did not help me